# Unable to download elementary os freya

Tags: elementary-website

There seems to be a problem when trying to download elementary.

Cnsole error:

Uncaught ReferenceError: release_title is not defined

Comment: var release_title = "Freya";
var release_version = '0.3';

In the console fixed it :D

Comment: This is likely due to an outdated cache file. Hard refresh ought to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

Answered [in the comments](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/7247/unable-to-download-elementary-os-freya#comment10446_7247) by [OP](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/users/5857/kristiqn-terziev):

> `var release_title = "Freya"; var release_version = '0.3';` In the console fixed it :D